# :contains regardless of case?

Tags: jquery, search

Im creating a basic search on a page.

Currently i'm using the code:

```
$.each($('p:contains('+keywords+')'), function(i, result){
```

to start things off, which works but only matching case. The keywords variable is likely to always be lowercase, however the word in the document may be uppercase or capitalized. How to check if 'p' contains the keywords regardless of case?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [blog post](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/make-jquery-contains-case-insensitive/) on how to make `:contains` case insensitive.

This is what they did:

```
$.expr[":"].contains = $.expr.createPseudo(function(arg) {
    return function( elem ) {
        return $(elem).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(arg.toUpperCase()) >= 0;
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter`

```
matchedElments = $('p').filter(function(i, result){
   return $(result).text().toLowerCase() == keywords;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you probably shouldn't use JavaScript to make a search engine. But, if you must, here's what you can do:

```
$.each($('p:contains('+keywords.toLowerCase()+')'), function(i, result){
```